# Can't understand how xargs is treating unicode literals

Tags: xargs, unicode

I'm trying to convert unicode literals into readable format.  I'm using the -t flag to see what command xargs is going to run before it runs it.  I see the following weirdness:

```
$ echo -n "\\\t\\\u0042\\\u0065\\\u006e" | xargs -t -I '{}' echo -e '"'{}'"'
echo -e "\t\u0042\u0065\u006e"
"       \u0042\u0065\u006e"
```

Yet when I run it manually:

```
$ echo -e "\t\u0042\u0065\u006e"
        Ben
$
```

The `\t` is being correctly processed in both examples.  but the `\u00XX` values are being treated as a plain string in the first example but is being encoded correctly in the second example.  I see the same weirdness when I use `printf` as well.

```
$echo -n "\\\t\\\u0042\\\u0065\\\u006e" | xargs -t -I '{}' printf \"{}\"
printf "\t\u0042\u0065\u006e"
"       printf: invalid universal character name \u0042
$ printf "\t\u0042\u0065\u006e"
        Ben
```

Any ideas on what's happening and how to fix it?

Comment: What shell are you using and does it have `echo` builtin? If so, try manually running `$(which echo) -e "..."` -- that'll be the one `xargs` is using

Comment: The shell is bash 4.4.  echo is at /bin/echo.

Comment: bash has `echo` builtin, and `printf` also. Try `/bin/echo -e "\u0042\u0065\u006e"` and `/bin/printf ""\u0042\u0065\u006e"` and you'll find those give the same results as `xargs`

Comment: Now it makes sense.  Thank you.  I would have never guessed there were two versions each of echo and printf floating about in my test problem.  

That solves my big issue of "why?"  I was able to find a workaround for my conversion problem with this:  `var=$(echo -n "\\t\\u0042\\u0065\\u006e"); echo  -e "$var". `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave is correct, the shell isn't involved, so the echo is /bin/echo, try this:

```
echo  "\\\t\\\u0042\\\u0065\\\u006e" | od -c

echo "\\\t\\\u0042\\\u0065\\\u006e" | xargs -t -I '{}' echo -e '"'{}'"'
 
# echo -e '"'\t\u0042\u0065\u006e'"'
/bin/echo -e '"'\\t\\u0042\\u0065\\u006e'"'
```

Result:

```
0000000   \   \   t   \   \   u   0   0   4   2   \   \   u   0   0   6
0000020   5   \   \   u   0   0   6   e  \n
0000031
"   \u0042\u0065\u006e"
"   \u0042\u0065\u006e"
echo -e "\t\u0042\u0065\u006e"
```

Tried with [online bash shell](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I replied also to Dave above.